# Separate authentication systems (and db tables) for admins/users on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm re-building a project for a client who basically has a large membership database. These members can login to manage their membership from the frontend. The admins who log into the backend are stored in a different db table.

I was looking at using a custom basic authentication for the admin and ion_auth for the frontend. My reasoning for using ion_auth on the front end is that in the future additional community-related bits and bobs may be added in, and I can foresee something like ion_auth's extra features.

However I cant help feeling this is a rather messy way of dealing with it. Combining the memberships and admin tables isn't an option, so whatever happens I need two auth's running. Is it possible.

Is it possible to run ion_auth effectively twice, or should I do the above and use ion_auth for frontend members and another authentication type (e.g custom) for admins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone ION_auth and rename it and remove some elements for admin login.  its just a library after all.

For a user login you should only really need to know if a user_id exists in the session, you dont really need to set "_is_logged_in" => 1.  As long as your session data is created/destroyed correctly, this is because a user_id should **only exist** if the proper login procedure is done.

For admin logins however you would need to set something like "admin_logged_in" => 1 or "horse_logged_in" => 1, naming conventions dont play a key part, you just need something to reference to let you know an admin is present.

If you store admin logins in a seperate table as you say, login should be as straight forward as a user login.

I have some codeigniter answers related to Auth(groups/permissions) If you want to check those out.

Good luck